# Why is my Django installation delivering an empty HTTP response?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

**Final Update:** There was a stray `LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.so` that conflicted with `mod_wsgi`. Removing that LoadModule made everything work again.

---

I am setting up a production server with Django and following along with [the Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/), yet receiving a blank page (or, as Chrome likes to report, `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error.`) when I visit `http://domain.com/mysite`.

```
# httpd.conf

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /home/gibson/mysite/django.wsgi
```

```
# django.wsgi

import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/gibson')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I've also attempted using a very basic mod_wsgi test application (as found in the [mod_wsgi wiki](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide)), which behaves as expected:

```
# django.wsgi (test)

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'i live!'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

Is there something else I could be forgetting? I appreciate the insight.

**small update:** For giggles, I checked my Apache error_log:

```
[notice] child pid 18356 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Googling for this gem returned some stuff about Django's caching mechanism (which I don't use) and conflicts with loading the mod_python module (which I've commented out in my httpd.conf).

**Update 2:** (comments removed for brevity)

```
# settings.py

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ADMINS = (
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': '/home/gibson/mysite/sqlite3.db',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
SECRET_KEY = '[redacted]'
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
)
```

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',)
```

Comment: is your project called `mysite`? and is your project (the folder 'mysite' located in `/home/gibson` And finally, can you paste the basic django settings, urls.py and the viewyou're trying to display?

The wsgi config seems correct.

Comment: Yes. Yes. And I'll go ahead and update the post. And, to clarify, there is currently no view.

Comment: Do you mean there is no template? So, what does your urls.py contain, and what URL are you requesting?

Comment: I may mean no template. Not really sure, though. :P Still learning. urls.py is above. I'm requesting the base URL: /mysite

Comment: Please see my "final update". I appreciate all the help so far, but I think this question is now null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure there are no conflicting modules installed in Apache. Specifically, check for mod_python or similar.