# Why is my Django installation delivering an empty HTTP response? (Additional)

Tags: python, django, wsgi

My question is based on the question linked below. I have the exact same problem. But the suggested fix does not work for me.

[Why is my Django installation delivering an empty HTTP response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375836/why-is-my-django-installation-delivering-an-empty-http-response)

Below is a list of items that I already have tried.

1. Removed mod_python load files in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled /etc/apache2/mods-available directories
2. Removed PHP4_Load files in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled and /etc/apache2/mods-available directories
3. Grep for "mod_python", "python_module" in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled, /etc/apache2/mods-available and etc/apache2 directories but did not find anymore references.
4. Tested "Hello world" example in django.wsgi file and it works fine.
5. Checked apache error log. Output is below. there is not error and an interpreter appears to be created.

> [Mon Aug 05 15:32:31 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=9246): Create
>   interpreter 'www.example.com|'.

6. Ran apache2ctl -M results are below.

   - Ran Loaded Modules:
   - core_module (static)
   - log_config_module (static)
   - logio_module (static)
   - mpm_prefork_module (static)
   - http_module (static)
   - so_module (static)
   - alias_module (shared)
   - auth_basic_module (shared)
   - authn_file_module (shared)
   - authz_default_module (shared)
   - authz_groupfile_module (shared)
   - authz_host_module (shared)
   - authz_user_module (shared)
   - autoindex_module (shared)
   - deflate_module (shared)
   - dir_module (shared)
   - env_module (shared)
   - mime_module (shared)
   - negotiation_module (shared)
   - reqtimeout_module (shared)
   - setenvif_module (shared)
   - status_module (shared)
   - wsgi_module (shared)
   - Syntax OK

I still receive a blank page response (unless the hello world is enabled).

Are there anymore suggestions for this? Any other places I can look for mod_python loading?

### django.wsgi file

```
#/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi


paths = ('/var/www/example.com/django/mysite',)
for path in paths:
    if path not in sys.path:
            sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

### django.wsgi hello world example (when enabled)

```
def application(environ, start_response):
   status='200 OK'
   output='Hello Yall'
   print >> environ['wsgi.errors'], "application debug #1"

response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

   if environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] == 'https':
         environ['HTTPS'] = 'on'

   start_response(status, response_headers)
   print >> environ['wsgi.errors'], "application debug #2"

   return [output]
```

### Apache file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        ServerAdmin example@example.com


       DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
       <Directory /var/www/example.com>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
       </Directory>

       WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.com/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
       <Directory /var/www/example.com/django/mysite/apache>
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer the question.  What does your urls.py look like? What does your view look like?  It's likely that the issue is with your view or perhaps urls.py - are you getting back a 200, or some other error code (the debug window of Chrome might be useful for this?)

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

in your Apache configuration.

This will work around issues with third party extension modules in Python that will not work with Python sub interpreters and can crash.

If that doesn't help, you likely have shared library conflict issues that are causing crashes.

Both of these issues are described in the official mod_wsgi documentation. So go check out the [Frequently Asked Questions](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/frequently-asked-questions.html) page in the mod_wsgi documentation for further links.